# Empty array being returned prior to the items being resolved as promises, processed and added

Tags: javascript

Any feedback appreciated on how to resolve / structure logic given async code? Thanks!

### Method

```
const getRelatedNodes = async (root) => {

    const n_nodes = []
    const links = await getAllLinks()

    links.forEach(async link => {

        const other_nodes = link.parties.filter(x => x.id != root.id)

        other_nodes.forEach(async party => {
            
            const obj = await fetchEntityById(party.id)

            console.log("Line 215! Received entity from promise => ", obj)

            const node = {
                "data": {
                    "output": obj.info,
                }
            }
            console.log("Line 222! pushing node to list => ", node)

            n_nodes.push(node)
        })
        console.log("Line 225! New node should be added to nodes list => ", n_nodes)
    })
    console.log("Line 229!!! Logging final output in getNodes =>" , n_nodes)
    // return n_nodes
}
```

**Expected Logging: Each node is pushed to the list after a promise returns an object to be modified**

```
Line 222! pushing node to list =>  { data: { output: 'Foo-tatstic' }}
Line 225! New node should be added to nodes list =>  [{ data: { output: 'foo' }}]

Line 215! Received entity from promise =>  { id: 'bar'  }
Line 222! pushing node to list =>  { data: { output: 'Bar-tatstic'} }
Line 225! New node should be added to nodes list =>  [{ data: { output: 'foo' }}, { data: { output: 'bar'} }]

Line 215! Received entity from promise =>  { id: 'baz' }
Line 222! pushing node to list =>  { data: { ouput: 'Baz-tatstic'} }
Line 225! New node should be added to nodes list =>  [{ data: { output: 'Foo-tatstic' }}, { data: { output: 'Bar-tatstic'} }, { data: { ouput: 'Baz-tatstic'} }]

Line 229!!! Logging final output in getNodes => [{ data: { output: 'Foo-tatstic' }}, { data: { output: 'Bar-tatstic'} }, { data: { ouput: 'Baz-tatstic'} }]
```

**Actual Logging: Nodes not getting added to list until after the list is returned**

```
Line 225! New node should be added to nodes list =>  []
Line 225! New node should be added to nodes list =>  []
Line 229!!! Logging final output in getNodes => []
Line 215! Received entity from promise =>  { id: 'foo', }
Line 222! pushing node to list =>  { data: { output: 'Foo-tatstic' }}
Line 215! Received entity from promise =>  { id: 'bar'  }
Line 222! pushing node to list =>  { data: { output: 'Bar-tatstic'} }
Line 215! Received entity from promise =>  { id: 'baz' }
Line 222! pushing node to list =>  { data: { output: 'Baz-tatstic'} }
```

Comment: This is caused by the part inside `forEach` being async since the code AFTER `forEach` won't wait for the `forEach` to finish its job.
Try putting the `forEach` part in a async function and put an `await` while calling that function before the `console.log("Line 225!....` line.

Comment: Hi @HarshGundecha! Makes a lot of sense, though still getting same result. I tried calling each `forEach` independently as async/await functions and both all with the same output